# Can't access file from another directory

Tags: php

So basically I have a php file in `/var/www/ankh.ga/public_html/bot/changelog.php`. I'm trying to make it read a file from `/root/changelog.txt`, however it keeps saying that the file does not exist. I've tried to include `./root` and just `/root` but they both say that the file doesn't exist. Is there a way I could possibly get changelog.php to include changelog.txt?

Website is running on a DigitalOcean VPS (Apache/Ubuntu) if that helps.

`/var/www/ankh.ga/public_html/bot/changelog.php`

```
<html>
<?php include '/var/www/ankh.ga/public_html/include/header.php'; ?>
<body align="left">
<h1 style="margin-left:20px;">
Changelog
</h1>
<pre><xmp style="font-family:monospace;background-color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;margin-left:20px;padding:10px;border-radius:10px;"><?php include '/root/changelog.txt'; ?></xmp></pre>
</body>
<?php include '/var/www/ankh.ga/public_html/include/footer.php'; ?>
</html>
```

Comment: Usually only the `root` user has access to the `/root` directory.

Comment: how would I do that in php?

Comment: Try pasting your code how you are accessing changelog.txt and what error are you getting.

Comment: Post the code and the error message.

Comment: pasted the code in.

Comment: The PHP code is executed by the web server that usually runs as `nobody` or `apache` or something similar. On most (all?) Unix systems, only the `root` user has access to the `/root` directory (for security reasons). You can change the permissions on `/root` to `rwx-----x` to let the webserver access a file stored in `/root` given it knows its name, if the admin web interface allows you to do it. Otherwise you can create a cron job (also using the admin web interface) that runs daily and copies `/root/changelog.txt` to `/var/www/ankh.ga` where the web server can read it.

Comment: This is an apache access issue. The apache user cannot access the root user directory. And actually you should not try this anyway, for security reasons.